# Am I allowed to use an open source Spritz clone in my app?

Tags: android, open-source, licensing, commercial-application

The Spritz technology generated a lot of buzz on the internet recently, and I'd like to incorporate that technology into my app. People have already open sourced it here: https://github.com/andrewgiang/SpritzerTextView

I am wondering if the fact that its GPLv3 licensed means I'm good to go, even commercially.

I understand that I'm not receiving legal advice from you guys.

EDIT: Based on OpenSpritz: https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/OpenSpritz-Android

Comment: I see Apache 2.0 in the link...

Comment: That is correct. It is based on OpenSpritz which is GPLv3. Sorry for the confusion.

Also to clarify, I am worried that anyone can just add whatever license to the works even if it is patent or copyright infringement. Is there a good way to verify if I'm in the clear or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the original software was GPLv3 and someone randomly stamped Apache 2.0 on a derived work, the GPLv3 will govern.

The GPL is infinitely more restrictive, it requires you to make source code available for any derived work, allow others to copy your work and distribute -- basically you don't own your code any more, the public does -- you are merely the steward.  As Steve Balmer described [Linux's GNU GLP], "it is a cancer that attaches itself in an intellectual property sense to everything it touches" -- can't think of a better way to say it.

Apache 2.0 on the other hand is permissive.  You can use the code, put in your program, use it commercially, and not have to provide the source code when someone requests.  In short, if your doing anything commercial, don't touch anything GPL, but Apache 2.0 fine.

More info:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749461/lgpl-mit-or-apache-differences
(someone posted a nice chart there.)

Comment: Couldn't I do something commercial, but still incorporate something GPL in it... I don't mind leaving my paid app open source. I think the vast majority of people will like the convenience provided by the auto-updates from the Play Store and not having to compile the code on their computer to transfer it to their phone :p Additionally, I don't think my app provides some novel algos or anything that someone couldn't come up with themselves.

Comment: Commercial use is allowed under GPLv3, but someone can come along and demand all your source code for your entire app, including all updates, change the title, and have a legal competing app to yours with no work.  GPLv3 infects basically any code using the GPL covered code.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me. I think that for my purpose that is a small worry as my project is mainly a resume builder, but I will take any money people want to pay me :)

Comment: It isn't infecting, its to prevent commercial entities from freeloading off the open source community.  With Apache and BSD they take our work, close it off, add minimal (or no) improvements to it and then claim copyright on their changes, preventing us from using or improving it further.  Basically, those licenses are trojan horses that allow commercial companies to come in and profit while contributing nothing back to society.  They're mistakes and nobody should write code using them.

Comment: thanks for the perspective on the other side; i see the problem you raise, but still the GPL stamp is a 75 year + life of the author effective patent against doing anything non-open source with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of SpritzerTextView and I am looking into this, OpenSpritz-Android is currently under GPLv3 and I have been working with that developer on his implementation of their SpritzerTextView.

OpenSpritz-Android might switch their library license to Apache 2 and will comply with the licence I have on my released version.

[Look here](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/OpenSpritz-Android/issues/39#issuecomment-37860397)